# Проблема кодировки строки

Tags: php

Как превратить такую строку в читабельную?

```
[7u2606] u00a76[MVPu00a7c++u00a76] u00a76truexackepu00a7f: u043fu0440u0438u0432u0435u0442
```

Comment: А до декодирования как выглядит строка? _(допишите её в пост с вопросом)_

Comment: выглядит также.

Comment: Дак с чего тогда вы взяли, что это json?

Comment: исправил...........

Comment: Исходная кодировка utf-8, но из нее удалили проценты. Последнее слово - привет, `u043fu0440u0438u0432u0435u0442` => `%u043f%u0440%u0438%u0432%u0435%u0442` => `привет`. Исходный текст что-то типа `[7☆] ੶[MVP੼++੶] ੶trxackep੿: привет`. [Декодер](https://2cyr.com/decode/)